Stockfish with Syzygy Support in Scid vs PC
My question is simple, yet rather sophisticated. It seems to me, that some people were able to set up Scid vs Pc (or Scid) in a way, that stockfish - or any derivative - is able to use offline syzygy-tablebases. At least i used the search engine of my choice and people are claiming do have done that.
I need help for doing exactly that:
What works fine is the setup via uci. What i mean by that, is hopefully understandable via the code below
stockfish

setoption name SyzygyPath value /path
position fen 8/P3R3/8/2R5/8/8/8/K1k2q2 b - -
d
go

I get a best move, the command "d" also gives am impression, that the position was recognised, however, i want the same feature to happen in scidvspc.
What i did is setting the syzygy-tablebase path via engine configuration, and indeed, it shows in the log, that it does see the tablebase. However, visually i have no proof, that it works, on the contrary it seems that stockfish is simply guessing the right moves.
How can i garantuee, that my setup is working?

In analysis window click Show info button. Analysis window will get topbar, in which you will see (among other things) number of tablebase hits.

thx a lot, i actually really have TB hits, (like 1,3 million within a short time), so i guess the setup is ok? I honestly thought, that the engine would stop calculating and tell me, that the postion is won and how it is won.

When engine gives very large evaluation (like +50) it usually means that it found solution in tablebase. To see distance to zero I think easiest is to use lichess analysis board - it queries 7-man tablebases in positions with 7 or less pieces, displaying list of moves with DTZ.

ok i get what you are saying, that would be completely fine with me.
However, in the mentioned position (ok, DTZ is 100), even after minutes of calculating, i dont get a +50 or anything else, i get +1.60.
Maybe the position is not ok, but hey, its about tablebases!
i dont get it...

How many pieces do your tablebases have? And can you share the fen of your position maybe?

FEN: 8/P3R3/8/2R5/8/8/8/K1k2q2 b - -
6 pieces tablebase (so far):
from the log info:
Engine: info string Found 365 WDL and 365 DTZ tablebase files (up to 6-man).
Scid  : setoption name SyzygyProbeDepth value 1
Scid  : setoption name Syzygy50MoveRule value false
Scid  : setoption name SyzygyProbeLimit value 6
